# How do I set a column as a "label" column in R?

Tags: r

I'm looking [at this tutorial](https://uc-r.github.io/kmeans_clustering#replication), which has state names as labels for each row in a dataframe.

I'm trying to do something similar with data that I upload from Excel but can't get kmeans clustering to work with any sort of non-numeric value.

My data essentially looks like this: 
Name, Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5
"New York", 1.5, -0.4, 1.6, 0.8, 0.9
...

Comment: Did you try using colnames(dataframe)[0] <- "name" to name the first column "name" ?

Comment: We need to see what your data looks like. You seem to be asking 2 different questions: how to add row names to a data frame and how to specify the columns used by kmeans.

Comment: Yeah, it's labeled as "Name" in row 1. I get this kmeans error when running it: "Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion"

Comment: More as how to specify the columns used by kmeans as actual data and which are considered labels

Comment: Can you try using `dput()` on your data frame so we can see what your data looks like? You can copy and paste the output into your question. So if your data frame is named (df), you would type into R `dput(df)`.

Comment: Oh. I figured it out. Used these three lines: rownames(df) = df$Name
df$Name = NULL
df = scale(df)